# How can I create an external HDD using a dual booted internal HDD?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I had an old laptop that I dual booted with ubuntu and windows 10. So I decided to use its internal hard drive as an external hard drive and bought the enclosure and everything needed.
The problem I am having is that my current laptop only has windows installed and I can only access the windows partition of the drive.
So how can I format the drive and make the entire drive accessible across all platforms(Windows, Linux, MAC and TV)

Comment: So you want to etwas all data on the disk and start over new? Use Windows diskmanager to edit petitions. This way you can delete all type of partitions no matter what OS has created it.

Comment: You’re trying to access the Linux partition of the internal drive contained within an enclosure? Your question is very vague, you should edit it, and clarify your question.  Your only answer doesn’t appear to answer what I suspect is your actual question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 7 does not recognize a Linux formatted hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/254266/windows-7-does-not-recognize-a-linux-formatted-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows' native [diskmgmt.msc](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/windows-10-disk-management-0528.html) or a third-party tool such as [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) to:

1. Remove all partitions, creating free space.
2. Create a single partition for the whole disk.
3. Format that partition using a file system that can be read by **all** devices. My choice would be NTFS, but that might require the [Mac to have NTFS access enabled](https://setapp.com/how-to/use-ntfs-for-mac), and Linux *might* need *fuse*, though [Ubuntu can natively read and write to NTFS](https://wiki.epfl.ch/icit/kb/linux-mount-ntfs-with-permissions).

**N.B.** *Before* you remove all partitions, use a tool such as [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) to access the *ext4* partition and recover whatever you want from the old HDD -- after removing the partitions, it will b gone.

Comment: For a wide compatibility exFAT seems a better choice than NTFS to me. It is natively supported on macOS without the need of some trick or third-party software, and as far as I can tell it is often supported out of the box under Linux. On devices likes TV etc, the support is never guaranteed, but this is the same for NTFS. Also, permissions can sometimes be a mess with a NTFS drive that is moved between computers: since exFAT doesn't manage permissions there can be no problem :)

Comment: FAT32 *is* natively supported on most systems, but **not** exFAT, a proprietary file system that may require *fuse* or other software to read it, and exFAT is usually *not* available at boot. The issues with FAT32 are that it's not designed for large files, wastes space for small files on large drives, and depends on a single TOC for integrity. Which FS to use, though is the user's choice -- which OS will be most used, is a journaled system needed, etc.

Comment: I didn't mention FAT32. You **are** recommanding NTFS in your answer, and I just wanted to raise attention that exFAT could be a choice as well.

Comment: @PierU, correct, you *did not* mention FAT32 , a viable choice. Since exFAT is proprietary, and would require special drivers (e.g. *fuse*) on all but Microsoft's OS, it is *not* a FS I'd use.

Comment: *"Since exFAT is proprietary..."*: true, but NTFS is proprietary as well. *"...and would require special drivers (e.g. fuse) on all but Microsoft's OS"*: that's just wrong; for the 3rd time I repeat that exFAT is natively supported on macOS (that is, with a kernel-level driver, not FUSE-based); regarding Linux there also exists a kernel module (again, not FUSE-based) for exFAT, which is now by default in many distributions.